# tvOS applicationDidBecomeActive called repeatedly with TV off

Tags: cocoa, tvos, revenuecat

On tvOS 13.4 with RevenueCat, when I have my app running on the 4K TV device, and then turn the TV off (leaving the app running), I get this:

```
2020-05-10 12:21:59-0700 MyApp[709:1904667] [Purchases] - INFO: Subscriber attributes synced successfully
2020-05-10 12:22:01-0700 MyApp[709:1904667] [Purchases] - INFO: Subscriber attributes synced successfully
2020-05-10 12:22:01-0700 MyApp[709:1904667] [Purchases] - DEBUG: applicationDidBecomeActive
2020-05-10 12:22:05-0700 MyApp[709:1904667] [Purchases] - INFO: Subscriber attributes synced successfully
2020-05-10 12:22:07-0700 MyApp[709:1904667] [Purchases] - INFO: Subscriber attributes synced successfully
2020-05-10 12:22:07-0700 MyApp[709:1904667] [Purchases] - DEBUG: applicationDidBecomeActive
2020-05-10 12:22:11.0700 MyApp[709:1904667] [Purchases] - INFO: Subscriber attributes synced successfully
2020-05-10 12:22:13-0700 MyApp[709:1904667] [Purchases] - INFO: Subscriber attributes synced successfully
2020-05-10 12:22:13-0700 MyApp[709:1904667] [Purchases] - DEBUG: applicationDidBecomeActive
2020-05-10 12:22:14-0700 MyApp[709:1904667] [Purchases] - INFO: Subscriber attributes synced successfully
2020-05-10 12:22:19-0700 MyApp[709:1904667] [Purchases] - INFO: Subscriber attributes synced successfully
2020-05-10 12:22:19-0700 MyApp[709:1904667] [Purchases] - DEBUG: applicationDidBecomeActive
```

Why might it be doing this? Obviously it knows the TV has been turned off since when I turn it back on, it stops doing these repeated calls.

The only call prior to this in the stack trace is a private function:

`#1 0x00000001e36c8398 in -[UIApplication _stopDeactivatingForReason:] ()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at RevenueCat, let me add some context:

This is caused by a bug in `purchases-ios`, present in versions `3.1.0` -> `3.2.2`, where the log gets issued even though the method no-ops, if there aren't any subscriber attributes that need to sync (which will be your case unless they're being set to different values very often).

It will be fixed in the next release, `3.2.3`, coming out this week (along with other fixes).

What's happening is that RevenueCat attempts to sync Subscriber Attributes (https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/subscriber-attributes) whenever the app is foregrounded or backgrounded. An app is considered foregrounded/backgrounded on tvOS when `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` or `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` get fired. If there are no attributes that need syncing, the method early exits, but the current version still issues the log saying that they've synced successfully.

I'm not quite sure why tvOS is firing those two notifications while the TV is off, but I'll dig in a bit more and let you know.

To clarify again, though, the method won't do anything unless new Subscriber Attributes have been set in between foregrounding or backgrounding, or unless they've been set to different values than the current ones.

Comment: Excellent! I assume 3.2.3 will be available with precompiled binaries for tvOS, iOS etc at GitHub zipped in a "Cartage" folder? It's much easier than compiling it myself.

Comment: Yep! It will as usual include pre-compiled binaries in the Carthage folder. Thanks for reporting and for your patience!